# Dependent RequestParam validation in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, http-request-parameters

I have a scenario where I have to rename one required request param. My application is already live. I want to deprecate the existing request param and want to add new request parameter. So my existing applications will be sending me the old request parameter and new application will start to send the new param.
Now I want to add validation, either I can mark both params as required or optional. But my business logic is either of param is required.

For example I already have a path parameter `group` and now I want to rename it to `pageGroup`. So either `page` or `pageGroup` is required.

How can I achieve it in Spring Boot? Any suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: Do you have a path parameter or request parameter as those are different things. Just write 2 handler methods each with a different parameter name and a `param` in the `@RequestMapping` annotation.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am dealing with request parameter so I think I can not add two different handler methods as path is not changing.

Comment: Yes you can, read my comment add the `param` argument to the `@RequestMapping` annotation.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have added a different handlers for both parameters using `params` and it worked perfectly. It might be a noob question for you but I was not aware of this :) Thanks man!

Comment: @M.Deinum I have another case, I can receive both parameters. In this case I am getting an exception :) Ambiguous handler methods mapped

Comment: Hey @AmjadAziz can you share a code snippet of your solution to have an overview? Will be helpful

Comment: If you do both parameters that won't be possible as, as you noticed, Spring cannot determine which method to call. Instead of using `@RequestParam` you can also manually extract the parameters from the `HttpServletRequest` and do the handling in the method.